# Ubuntu 10.04 slow on a Dell Optiplex 360 

Tags: performance, ubuntu-10.04

My desktop is becoming very slow - even when the load as displayed by the `w` command is around 2 or so. I run eclipse, crashplan, dropbox, and some times matlab. Chrome is the browser used. I have 4GB RAM.

I run `top` to see if any offender is there but I am unable to figure out anything abnormal.

```
$vmstat
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
0  2 1761116 662420 380944 332976   20    8   312   342    1   18  3  3 85 10

$free
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:     3983388    3310076     673312          0     391452     329764
-/+ buffers/cache:  2588860    1394528
Swap:    3999736    1762708    2237028
```

EDIT 1

I find that there around 10 chrome processes running ( I have only 5 tabs in chrome browser) occupying significant amount of memory (observed from System->Montior->Processes). Could this be a culprit or is it normal?

EDIT 2

It looks like it is the continuous hard disk access that slows down my machine as seen from the hard disk access LED. Now how do I go further?

Any suggestions?

suresh

Comment: Can you post the results of a `vmstat` and a `free`?

Comment: System Monitor -> Processes

Comment: @Aki Couldnt find anything particular....should I look for something specific?

Comment: @Paul I have added `vmstat` and `free` outputs.

Comment: Was these taken when you were experiencing slowness?

Comment: @Paul when I ran `vmstat` and `free`, my machine was not that deadly slow, but it was slower.